# Is it possible to disabled specific field in specific node for user in UmbracoCMS (Umbraco7)

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am trying to disabled specific field in specific nodeType for users of type 'writer' so they will not be able to change them (if there is no alternative, so hide just the same field its also ok..), but I need them to have access to the rest of the node content (watch and change!).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Check **Backoffice Tweaking** package: https://our.umbraco.org/projects/collaboration/backoffice-tweaking/. It's still in beta, so test it first! :) Unfrotunately there isn't any easy (& built-in) way to achieve this goal.